# How to estimate the parameter of copula family with GARCH and GJR-GARCH marginal model?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, garch, copula

How to estimate the parameter of copula family with GARCH and GJR-GARCH marginal model?

I need the R script of [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167668709001267).

Comment: Check out the "rmgarch" package. It has a nice [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fitting copula is usually done in in multiple steps:
1) You fit the marginal distributions independently (here your GJR-GARCH). I haven't done it on `R`, but apparently there few packages that allow you to perform this;
2) You construct pseudo-probabilities. If you are fully parametric, you would plug the residuals and the estimated parameters into the assumed CDF, i.e. $\hat{u}_i = F(x_i,\hat{\theta})$.
3) Eventually you fit the copula on these pseudo-probabilities.
I did not check the paper you mention, but I believe they do something similar. If they did something very specific, you can always write to the authors to ask their code.